# IDE With Autocompletion For Redis

Tags: ide, redis

Is there any IDE which provides auto completion for Redis?
With the ones i use currently, i need to type out everything, but it would surely be nice and time saving to have auto completion and syntax corrections?

Comment: You mean autocompletion of Redis keys (key names)?

Comment: yes, as well as for other constructs (i mean other relevant keywords) just as eclipse provides for java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Disclaimer] I'm the founder of Redsmin*

**[Redsmin](https://redsmin.com)** is an online Redis GUI that provides **commands and keys** auto-completion out-of-the-box as well as inline-documentation.

Start writing what you want, hit tab > select > up/down -> enter and you're done.

[image: redsmin commands auto-completion]
[image: redsmin keys auto-completion]

Redsmin is indeed not an IDE but is a tool of great help when developing redis-based applications.

PS: We currently do not support syntax correction but I took the liberty to **[add this feature to our roadmap](http://redsmin.uservoice.com/forums/173279-general/suggestions/4043491-terminal-support-for-syntax-correction)**, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, sounds very interesting. Looking forward to starting with it.

Comment: @FGRibreau, you better update your SSL certificate! It now shows: http://postimg.org/image/hki7pmezn/

Comment: @OferZelig I'm on it! Thanks for the report :)

Answer (score 0):

The redis-cli client has tab autocompletion enabled. I'm not aware of any IDE for Redis, and am not sure how this would work, since Redis is almost always embedded in another language through some client library.